# Normalize an array of floating point numbers so that sum is exactly 1.0

Tags: javascript

I would like to normalize an array of floating point numbers so that sum is exactly 1.0. Even if after normalization, if the sum is not exactly 1.0, input numbers should be tweaked minimally so that sum becomes exactly 1.0. The question is, what exactly should be that small change?

I tried a simple approach of summing all numbers and then dividing by the sum. But this does not work always. I tried also to set the value of the first number to 1.0 - sum of other numbers, but that also does not work always.

Using random search I found some examples of such values:

```
[0.28929993489784822103, 0.31008623188441802876, 0.19065357835268603726, 0.20996025486504751867]
[0.27449260698927169244, 0.26390952678124363073, 0.14345190180088057685, 0.31814596442860426651]
[0.28999999999999998002, 0.28999999999999998002, 0.29999999999999998890, 0.11999999999999999556]
[0.41999999999999998446, 0.14999999999999999445, 0.30999999999999999778, 0.13000000000000000444]
[0.29000000000000003553, 0.29000000000000003553, 0.29999999999999982236, 0.12000000000000000944]
[0.30693069306930698126, 0.28712871287128693965, 0.28712871287128716169, 0.11881188118811883414]
```

Preferably in JavaScript, but probably it does not matter.

Comment: Can you share the example array and the desired normalized array for better understanding

Comment: Are you mixing audio by chance?  If so, there are much easier and more efficient ways for compression and limiting with the Web Audio API.

Comment: Yes, this sounds like an X/Y problem

Comment: Example arrays are above. Normalized arrays are any where sum is 1.0 and values are as close as possible to the input values.

Comment: It is not music, but probabilities.

Comment: Unfortunately, floating-point addition is not associative (for example, `(0.1 + 0.1) + 0.4 != 0.1 + (0.1 + 0.4)`), so if you're interested in anything *exact*, then you can't even refer to the "sum" of an entire array without qualification.

Comment: Hm, good points about associativity. Let's relax then, so summing can be done in any, but deterministic, way. And for that summation, sum has to be 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. My summation was problematic and accumulated an error which then leads to normalization misbehaving. After switching to [Kahan summation algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) I am unable to find a counter-example using a random search.

My full algorithm now (in CoffeeScript):

```
preciseSum: (values...) ->
  values = _.flatten values

  sum = 0.0
  compensation = 0.0
  for value in values
    valueWithCompensation = value - compensation
    temp = sum + valueWithCompensation
    compensation = (temp - sum) - valueWithCompensation
    sum = temp

  sum

normalize: (values) ->
  if values.length is 1
    values[0] = 1.0
  else if values.length
    sum = 0.0
    i = 0
    while sum isnt 1.0
      assert i < 100
      i++

      sum = preciseSum values

      if sum is 0.0
        for value, j in values
          values[j] = 1.0
        continue

      for value, j in values
        values[j] = value / sum

      sum = preciseSum values

      if sum isnt 1.0
        partialSum = preciseSum values[1..]
        values[0] = 1.0 - partialSum

        sum = preciseSum values

  values
```